# Binding to dependency property via PlacementTarget fails - wrong path syntax?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

**No problem**

I created a dependency property which takes a string value. I set it on a `TextBlock` and it works:

```
<TextBlock dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName="LvMain">
```

I verified that the property `ElementDataContext.ElementName` is set to "LvMain".

**Problem**

Now here is the problem: in the `TextBlock`'s context menu I want to bind to this dependency property **via `PlacementTarget`**.

Here is how I try to do it. This is an excerpt of my XAML containing `TextBlock` and `ContextMenu`:

```
<TextBlock dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName="LvMain">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Tag="{Binding PlacementTarget.(dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

This fails at runtime. When opening the context menu it gives me a "BindingExpression path error":

```
BindingExpression path error: '(dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName)' property not found on 'object' ''TextBlock' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.(dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName); DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name='contextMenu'); target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name='contextMenu'); target property is 'Tag' (type 'Object')
```

I suspect my binding path is wrong. I tried

- `PlacementTarget.(dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName)`
- `PlacementTarget.dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName`
- `PlacementTarget.ElementDataContext.ElementName`

Nothing works. What is the correct syntax? Is this even possible?

Comment: Look at this: http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html may be can help you to find more info about the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property path syntax `PlacementTarget.(dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName)` is correct, but you also have to explicitly write the `Path=...` part in the property expression:

```
<ContextMenu Tag="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.(dp:ElementDataContext.ElementName),
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

However, the *Implicit Path* section in [Binding Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413.aspx) does not mention this behaviour.

Comment: Narf. That's it, thank you very much! So easy and an error message so not helpful.